# Synchronize one directory in a git repo with svn

Tags: git, svn

We have a git repo containing an R package plus a separate folder with associated non-R utilities. Both live happily together on bitbucket, but now the R package is also going into a public R-specific repo that is svn-based.

Is there a reasonably easy way to keep the svn repo in sync with just one folder of the git repo?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at git-svn.

It provides utilities for synchronising both ways.

```
git svn dcommit
```

in particular pushes your most recent changes into a subversion repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn would as always be the best reference.

If you're looking for tools to do this automatically, then I would just tend to use whatever CI setup you have (Jenkins?) to execute this command upon a successful a successful merge to master or what not.

Comment: Thanks, this is what we were intending to do. But is it suitable for a situation where we want to sync only a part of our git repo with svn?